# Get id value from same table in query

Tags: mysql

I have this table setup:

```
orders:
 id, order_nr

orders_cart:
id, orders_id,ref_backorder
```

Some data:

```
Orders:
id order_nr
1  012345
2  0123456

Orders_cart
id, orders_id, ref_backorder
1   2          1
1   1
```

the ref_backorder is a reference to another row in the same table.

```
Expected output:
    id, ref_backorder
    1    012345
    2    null
```

My query:

```
SELECT o.id, o.ref_backorder`
FROM orders_cart o 
??
LEFT JOIN orders ON o.ref_backorder` = orders.id 
??
```

How can i get the ref_backorder as order_nr?
ref_backorder is an id from a row. In this case row 1, in row 1 we have an orders_id 2. The value of orders_id 2 (0123456) is the value what I want to show in the query.

Can you join the table to itself?

Comment: i don't understand the expected output? you say you expct ref_backorder but the value under it is order_nr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the query could be this

```
select o.order_nr
from order 
inner join orders_cart as c on c.ref_backorder = o.id
where c.orders_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.id, A.orders_id, A.ref_backorder, B.order_nr FROM orders_cart AS A
JOIN orders AS B ON
    A.orders_id = B.id
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: You could easily say the same thing to the answer that was accepted.